# How to evaluate $\lim _{x\to -3}\frac{|x+3|}{x^2\:-\:9}$ without using L'hopital?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am in my first month of calculus 1. I need to evaluate the following limit:

$\lim _{x\to -3}\frac{|x+3|}{x^2\:-\:9}$

I don't know what to do with the absolute value sign.

Also, am I right that the limit equals 0. Or does it not exist?

Comment: Sorry you are right. Let me edit.

Comment: You can compute the $2$ one-sided limits and compare them.

Comment: I'm not sure what the one-sided limit (both sides?) would like.

Comment: **Bunch of hints:** Investigate the limit from the left and that which is from the right. Note that from the left $|x+3|=-x-3$ and from the right $|x+3|=x+3$.

Comment: I'd be surprised with an answer using L'hôpital.

Comment: @GitGud Well, I have students who use Hospital's rule over and over and over again on a problem like $\frac{e^{4x}+x+1}{e^{4x}+3}$ (with $x$ to infinity) And they get mad that this e-power doesn't go away :)

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$\lim_{x\to -3+0}\frac{|x+3|}{x^2-9}=\lim_{x\to -3+0}\frac{x+3}{(x+3)(x-3)}=\lim_{x\to -3+0}\frac{1}{x-3}=-\frac 16$$
and that
$$\lim_{x\to -3-0}\frac{|x+3|}{x^2-9}=\lim_{x\to -3-0}\frac{-(x+3)}{(x+3)(x-3)}=\lim_{x\to -3-0}-\frac{1}{x-3}=\frac 16.$$

Comment: @Joey: This is one-sided limit.

Comment: Typo, it should be $\mp\tfrac16$, you made a mistake when cancelling.

Comment: @Hakim: Thanks:)

Comment: Why does this website say otherwise:http://symbolab.com/solver/limit-calculator/%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto-3%7D%5Cfrac%7B%7Cx%2B3%7C%7D%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%20%2B%209%7D/?origin=enterkey

Comment: @Joey: Note that the denominator of the link is $x^2\color{red}{+}9$.

Comment: Nice catch mathlove. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Joey: You are welcome.

Comment: @Joey: So, your question is actually about $\frac{|x+3|}{x^2\color{red}{+}9}$ ?